PADES certificate signature not validating but approval signatures validate (DocMDP)
I've created a document with a PADES approval signature, which works fine, when digitally signed, but fails when i try add a DocMDP dictionary to turn the first signature into a certification/Author signature. (documents linked below)
Approval Signature
This first document shows the approval signature which is validating..


Certification Signature
The second document is a certification signature.. i've added a DocMDP dictionary to the document and copied the first signature dictionary into that.


Both DER encoded signer objects are the same in both sigs.
What i'm trying to achieve
This is an Adobe certification signature.. my PDF dictionary structure is the same as that and everything looks the same.

The issue (maybe)
I think my issue might be to do with the ByteRange i sign. With the Approval signature the ByteRang is 0 to the start of the /Contents signature field, which when captured contains a default byte range placeholder. Then from the end of the contents to the end of the file.. [0, 11347, 31349, 4448]
But when adding a DocMDP, because the byteRang is 4 digits, and the /contents default placeholder has been duplicated to the DocMDP, the creation signature ByteRange includes the full contents of the default byte range in there, which obviously changes when replaced with the signature object after signing.. [0, 11361, 31363, 24958]
I've tried using a six digit ByteRange to bypass the DocMDP contents field as well but that didnt work, and also the correctly signed Adobe document only uses 4 digits. I can't find any info on how to get around this and what the ByteRange should cover in this situation. This is the Adobe document's DocMDP dictionary i'm referencing, which you can see the last digit is a lot smaller..

Reference documents

Signed with Approval
Signed with Certification
Signed Adobe document


Both "Signed with Approval" and "Signed with Certification" point to the identical file.


The second document is a certification signature.. i've added a DocMDP dictionary to the document and copied the first signature dictionary into that.

And this already is the error: If you copy the signature dictionary, you suddenly have two places where you have to insert a signature upon signing, and each of those signatures has to sign the whole PDF file except it itself. This cannot work.
What you want to do instead of copying the original signature dictionary there, is referencing the original signature dictionary from there.
Have a look at your example Adobe signed document, there both the V of the signature field and the DocMDP of the Perms refer to object 28, while in your document the V of the signature field refers to object 12 and the DocMDP of the Perms refers to object 13.

mkl thanks for that.. it was the issue.. and is now showing as a certification.. but it's showing a prob in adobe, "signature is invalid".. i have uploaded the self-signed certificate to adobe and also give it certify documents privileges... it shows the signature is correct in the EU demo validator.. Do you have any idea what i need to do to get the Rosette to show in Adobe? here is the updated file - signed with certification

I'll take a look in the next days, not today, though.

Sure, no probs. I run it through a signature verification script and it says the signature is valid, so i'm thinking that it might be something to do with the self-signed certificates in Adobe, i'll see if i can figure it out. Thanks.

At first and second glance I only see an error in your TransformParams dictionary, you use a float as value of the V version entry: 1.2. According to spec, though, it has to be a name, i.e. /1.2.

Wow, yes that was it. I turned it into a string and its all showing correct. Thanks again mkl, your direct answers and answers to other peoples issues have been a massive help to us on this project.
